# Doxygen warning "does not have an associated number"

Tags: doxygen, bibtex

I am using doxygen 1.8.9.1 and bibtex to generate the reference list. It looks doxygen (or bibtex) don't support longer key.

For example, my bib file looks like

```
@incollection{mcmaster_phenology_,
    title = {The {DSSAT} cropping system model},
    volume = {18},
    journaltitle = {European Journal of Agronomy},
    author = {A, F.},
}

@article{mcmaster_phenology_1,
    title = {The {DSSAT} cropping system model},
    volume = {18},
    journaltitle = {European Journal of Agronomy},
    author = {A, F.},
}
```

My text.cs file looks

```
namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A test class
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This is test citation, see \cite mcmaster_phenology_ and 
    /// \cite mcmaster_phenology_1.
    /// </remarks>
    public class TestClass
    {
    }

}
```

The warning message is:

```
warning: \cite command to 'mcmaster_phenology_1' does not have an associated number
```

The final html is

```
This is test citation, see [1] and [mcmaster_phenology_1].
```

Seems the maximum length of key is 19 characters. It looks a bug for me. How should I fix it? Thank for any suggestions.

Comment: Based on the information above I tried to reproduce it with doxygen 1.8.9.1 on Windows but was not successful. Can you create a complete, small, example to show the problem.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. Doxygen (or bibtex) doesn't support longer keys. Will edit my question.

Comment: I've did some tests and it looks indeed that doxygen.bst (called from bib2xhtml.pl) causes the problem. bibtex is called here and the .aux file for the bibtex call is OK but the resulting .bbl file is wrong. Unfortunately I've not been able to spot the problem, please submit a bug report in bugzilla (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen )

Comment: @albert Thanks for your test. A bug report is submitted. Please let me know if you need more information.